# How to copy a component from one page to another in touch UI AEM?

Tags: aem, aem-touch-ui

I want to copy a component from one page to another page in touch UI AEM. How can we achieve that?

Comment: There are many ways of performing this. Can you be more specific? Do you want to accomplish this as a developer or content author? What AEM version are you using?
One way could be to add parsys/responsiveGrid component to the page and just add the same component on that parsys/responsiveGrid

Comment: I want to accomplish as a developer. I am using 6.2 version.

Comment: Also, i want to add the component in a different page which has different template. Not within the same same page or within the same parsys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to open **html** of the page you want to add component on, and perform **one** of these:

Adding component directly on the page:

```
<article data-sly-resource="${'componentName' @ prependPath='path/to/the/component'}"></article>
```

Adding parsys component, and then drag&drop component on that parsys:

```
<cq:include path="par" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" />
```

You can add component on page/template in many different ways that depends on your exact need.

Comment: How to accomplish as an author? As a developer i cant add all the components in each of the HTML pages. Content author should have the flexibility.

Comment: I got the other way round option. Thanks.

Comment: Then it would be good if you add it to template that sites are using. It would be good if you provide your solution to the answer so it might help somebody else.

Comment: Yap, curious about @Amit's solution